# Validate interface using IoC

Tags: .net, inversion-of-control, validation-application-bl

I have a domain model that uses IoC with Microsoft Unity.
For the validation I use VAB and I decorate the interface, not the entity.
The code the following:

```
interface IJob : IValidable
{
 [NotNullValidator]
 string Name { get; set; }
}

interface IValidable
{
 bool IsValid { get; }
 void ValidationResults Validate();
}

class Job : IJob
{
 string Name { get; set; }

 public virtual bool IsValid
 {
    get { try
         {
            return Validate().IsValid;
         }
         catch
         {
            return false;
         } }
 }

 public ValidationResults Validate()
 {
   return Validation.Validate(this);
 }

}
```

If I decorate directly the class with the VAB attributes, the validation works. If I use the validation only in the interface, it doesn't.
This is how we render a new instance:

```
ioC.RegisterType<IJob, Job>();
IJob job = ioC.Resolve<IJob>();
return job.IsValid;
```

The code works if the validation attributes are also in the class, otherwise it doesn't.
Why?

Comment: Ok I am sorry, next time I will google before posting.
This is the problem with the related solution: http://entlib.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=10450

Answer (score 1):

The correct implementation will be:

```
ValidationFactory.CreateValidator<IJob>().Validate(job);
```

In order to do that, my interface IValidable has became IValidable where

```
interface IJob : IValidable<IJob> {  }
```

In this way I will be able to validate against the interface. So I will recycle this interface to validate also the Dto!

:D